# Generate Values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel Spreadsheet. I have a row in which I input an initial value, a year, a count, and a value.

Below this row, I want to generate information for each year, based on the inputs. For instance, if I enter $1000 for the initial value, 2013 for the year, 5 for the count, and 500 for the value, I want to generate the following:

```
Year   Total 
----   -----
2013   1000
2014   1500
2015   2000
2016   2500
2017   3000
```

How do I generate those values in Excel? Thank you!

Comment: I can see what you pretend to do (i.e. simple interest adding) but in the future, describing your actual problem might bring better answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Excel 2010, but in 2013 it should work the same.
[image]

Comment: Neat gif, although you missed the part where the OP stated he had those values on other cells.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Had to read the question twice again.
I think this can be done with some kind of macro (otherwise I can't think about any other way), but I'm not entirely sure how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the following layout

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 |1000 |2013 |  5  | 500 |
```

Where `A1` is the initial value, `B1` is the starting year, `C1` is the amount of years the "interest" piles up and `D1` the simple interest (e.g. what you add to the value after a year passes).

So, in order to get the following:

```
  |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  |
--+-----+-----+-----+-----+
1 |1000 |2013 |  5  | 500 |
2 |     |     |
3 |Year |Total|
4 |2013 |1000 |
5 |2014 |1500 |
6 |2015 |2000 |
7 |2016 |2500 |
8 |2017 |3000 |
```

make the following:

- `A4` : `=B1`
- `B4` : `=A1`

This defines the initial values. The next cells have different values in order to reflect the changes. Assuming you are doing this from 1 year intervals, then:

- `A5` : `=A4 + 1`
- `B5` : `=IF(A5-$A$4 <= $C$1; $B$4 + (A5-$A$4)*$D$1; $B$4 + $C$1*$D$1)`

The first only adds 1 to the previous year's value, so that when you drag the cell below all years will be ordered.

The second is a conditional statement, essentially, if the difference between the current and the start year is equal or less than the number of years the interest piles up (5) then the condition is `TRUE` and Excel computes the beginning value plus the amount of interest that piled up in between the years. If the year exceeds the end year, then the result equals the last year where interest was paid. Hence the cell locking (the `$` sign prepended to the row and column identifier) is used.

You can then drag the 4th row downwards and get those values automatically.

I've done this all in my head, so I might have some slight mistakes, but this works in principle.

Answer (score 1):

Place your inputs in **A1** thru **D1** and run this small macro:

```
Sub TableMaker()
    init = [A1]
    yr = [B1]
    kount = [C1]
    incr = [D1]
    j = 2
    For i = 1 To kount
        Cells(j, 1) = yr
        Cells(j, 2) = init
        j = j + 1
        yr = yr + 1
        init = init + incr
    Next i
End Sub
```